# Ldap user defined attributes not retrieved when accessed through java on linux server

Tags: java, ldap, openldap

I am using 'jldap' for accessing and updating ldap attributes in java.

Code works fine when I run it in eclipse on my windows machine.

But, when I run it on linux server it is not able to access/read 'user defined attributes' for each ldap entry.

I am not able to figure out why this is happening.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 'Not able to access' is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: Then what do you suggest it should be ?

Answer (score 0):

When a connection is first established to a directory server, that connection has no (or anonymous) authorization state. The BIND operation is used to set the authorization state of a connection. It might be that one **authorization state in one part of the test is different from the authorization state of the other part of the test**.

Consider using the known good LDAP client `ldapsearch` to emulate and validate the client, and supply the same search parameters to `ldapsearch` to validate the results are as expected.

Consider using the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) instead of JNDI for new code. Very generally speaking, JNDI should not be used for new code.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)